# How to trigger stop method for react-player to stop and end video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

How to trigger stop method for `react-player` to stop and end video? Here is my code:

```js
<ReactPlayer
  className="react-player mw-100 w-100 "
  id="myPlayer"
  ref={(player) => {
    this.player = player;
  }}
  url={VIMEO_URL}
  onStart={() => {
    this.player.seekTo(this.getProgress());
  }}
  onPlay={() => this.play(this)}
  onPause={() => this.pause()}
  onDuration={this.handleDuration}
  onProgress={this._recordProgress}
  onReady={() => this.player.seekTo(this.getProgress())}
/>;
```

Comment: You want to stop from playing the video programatically ?

Comment: yes, though the external function i want to stop the video

Answer (score 0):

Try using the playing proerty:

```js
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);

<ReactPlayer
  playing={isPlaying}
  className="react-player mw-100 w-100 "
  id="myPlayer"
  ref={(player) => {
    this.player = player;
  }}
  url={VIMEO_URL}
  onStart={() => {
    this.player.seekTo(this.getProgress());
  }}
  onPlay={() => this.play(this)}
  onPause={() => this.pause()}
  onDuration={this.handleDuration}
  onProgress={this._recordProgress}
  onReady={() => this.player.seekTo(this.getProgress())}
/>;
```

Comment: yes, this solution will pause the video, but my requirement is to stop the video

Comment: @ChandraPrakash did you get a way around this?